# Meteor: Minimongo does not synchronize with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor, angular, typescript

My Meteor application using Angular 2 and Typescript seems not to load the server data on the client side: I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/3-way-data-binding), both with autopublish turned on and of, but each time several tries to display data on client side with different collections failed.

Unlike in the tutorial (RC4), I am using Angular 2 RC5. My clients' main.ts looks as following:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule }              from './app.module';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Now I tried to copy the very simple sample from the tutorial using the collection "parties" (autopublish turned on).

I created the file **both/collections/parties.collection.ts**:

```
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
import {Party} from '../interfaces/party.interface';
export const Parties = new Mongo.Collection<Party>('parties');
```

Instead of using the app.component.ts, I bind the collection in an another existing and functional component which looks like following:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import template from './my-component.component.html';
import { Parties }   from '../../../both/collections/parties.collection';
import { Party } from '../../../both/interfaces/party.interface';

@Component({
selector: 'my-selector',
template
})

export class MyComponent
{
    parties: Mongo.Cursor<Party>;

    constructor() {
        this.parties = Parties.find();
        alert(this.parties.count());
    }
}
```

If I call **db.parties.find({});** in the mongo console, it returns three rows, because I have set up the server side inserts from the sample.

My html template is the same as in the tutorial:

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let party of parties">
  <a [routerLink]="['/party', party._id]">{{party.name}}</a>
  <p>{{party.description}}</p>
  <p>{{party.location}}</p>
  <button (click)="removeParty(party)">X</button>
</li>
```

alert(this.parties.count()) returns "0" - both trying Mongo.Cursor and Mongo.Cursor. I have also tried to fetch the cursor and to alert the array. Each time I get "0" and the error message **"NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."**, but I think it fails because the client does not get the data the server has.

Comment: It sounds like your `Parties` Collection isn't available server side. Are you sure it's being referenced/loaded server side? For example, are you importing `both/collections/parties.collection` in something like `/server/main.ts`?

Comment: The discussion concerning this issue is going on in the meteor forum: https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-minimongo-does-not-synchronize-with-mongodb/29235

Answer (score 0):

This is no more an issue on recent versions of  angular2.0-meteor.